# Sequelize sync duplicates existing foreign key associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am encountering an issue where the `sync` functionality of `Sequelize` duplicates existing Foreign Key Associations in every `sync` execution.

Couldn't solve the issue and couldn't find any solution here or somewhere else therefore I am sharing the problem here.

---

So, this demonstrates how it looks like when you execute the all the code block for the very first time. It creates the same foreign key twice.

[image]
[image]

---

And this demonstrates how it looks like when you execute the code for the second time. Now there is a third one.

[image]
[image]

---

Eight times...

[image]
[image]

---

... and so on.

---

Dependencies, `package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "lab-sequelize",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^8.5.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src"
  }
}
```

The entire code block, `index.js`:
The code below establishes a database (postgres) connection, initializes models and synchronizes them to the database using `Sequelize`.

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: 5432,
    database: "mydb",
    username: "myusername",
    password: "mypassword",
    dialect: "postgres",
    logging: console.log,
});

const schemaName = 'aschema';

async function main() {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Establish the connection
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create db schema
    await sequelize.createSchema(schemaName);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Define models

    const Company = sequelize.define('company', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
    }, {
        schema: schemaName,
        // freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'company'
    });

    const User = sequelize.define('user', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        companyId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        // aNewPotentialField: {
        //     type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        // }
    }, {
        schema: schemaName,
        // freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'user'
    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Set relations
    User.belongsTo(Company, { as: 'company', foreignKey: 'companyId' });
    // Company.hasOne(User, { as: 'users', foreignKey: 'companyId' });

    // User.belongsTo(Company);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Sync

    // * These syncs below multiply the existing relations.
    // * Will add the field 'aNewPotentialField' in the future since alter set to true.
    await Company.sync({ alter: true });
    await User.sync({ alter: true });

    // * These syncs below don't multiply the existing relations.
    // * However, also wont add the field 'aNewPotentialField' in the future since alter set to false.
    // await Company.sync();
    // await User.sync();

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Close the established connection.
    await sequelize.close();
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}


main()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('App started successfully.');
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        throw e;
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code? This works best to create the initial schema, if it already exists you should look at using migrations to modify it.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the entire code establishes a database (postgres) connection, initializes models and synchronizes them to the database using `Sequelize`. Lets imagine it runs right before deploying your web application which uses the same model. Before moving on to migration, I want to figure out why `sync` duplicates FK relations here.

Comment: If you just want to create the initial database if you pass in `force: true` it will drop and recreate the tables, which should also remove the references. This will lose any data as well. If you are deploying a new version of the web app you should run the migration and then deploy the new code.

Answer (score 1):

Investigated it closer and found that this issue occurs when `schema` option is provided to model(s).

According to the execusion logs, `queryGenerator.getForeignKeyReferencesQuery (dialects/postgres)` in Sequelize generates wrong query.

```sql
... WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND tc.table_name = '"aschema"."user"' AND tc.table_catalog = 'testdb'
```

Where it has to be:

```sql
... WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND tc.table_name = 'user' AND tc.table_catalog = 'testdb' AND tc.table_schema = 'aschema'
```

And there is also another thing in `query-interface` causes the issue.

[PR for the fix can be found here now](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12833)